# Google APIs - removing auth scope

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-classroom

I'm changing scopes in an app for Google Classroom. I remove from courses `.readonly` and added student listing

```
var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students";
```

I get this error when requesting students even after logging out and attempting to re-authenticate:

> Request had insufficient authentication scopes

It seems the token has been cached somewhere.

[This Github issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/776), although for Google Sheets, says the token is in `Documents/.credentials/` folder. I don't have this folder though on my Macbook Pro Sierra `10.12.6`.

Where can I find that folder and remove the saved scopes so it reauthenticates and accepts my new scopes?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the scopes needed in your application then the user will need to authenticate your application. especially if you go from a read-only scope to a read write scope.  This is because you need additional permissions then what you had originally requested.  [List of google classroom scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#classroomv1)

Assuming that you are using the Google .net client library then you can find the user credentials in the %appdata% folder on your machine.  By deleting that fine you can force a authentication.  I am guessing that you are since this is the github project you have linked to.

Note: there should be a way of forcing reauth via code but i cant remember the command right now i will have to look it up.